# PyQt5 Threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qdialog

Attempting to write a class that will show the progress of a threaded process.  I need to use this class for all "file load" operations; however I am having trouble making it global.

fileloader.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class FileLoader(QDialog):
    completeSig = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FileLoader, self).__init__(parent)
        self.filename = ""
        self.clientcode = ""
        self.thread = ""
        loadUi("GlobalUI/fileloader.ui", self)
        self.prgLoader.setValue(0)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_btnCancel_clicked(self):
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        self.thread.stop()

    def loadData(self):
        self.thread.totalSig.connect(self.prgLoader.setMaximum)
        self.thread.countSig.connect(self.prgLoader.setValue)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.completed)
        self.thread.start()

    def completed(self):
        self.completeSig.emit()
        self.close()
```

loader.py

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QThread

from fileloader import FileLoader


class DataLoader(QThread):
    totalSig = pyqtSignal(int)
    countSig = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DataLoader, self).__init__(parent)
        self.threadactive = True
        self.commitsize = 300
        self.rowdata = []

    def run(self):
        print("Code Will Go Here For Loading the File")

    def stop(self):
        self.threadactive = False
        self.wait()


class PatDataLoader():
    def load(self, clientcode, filename):
        fl = FileLoader()
        fl.clientcode = clientcode
        fl.filename = filename
        fl.thread = DataLoader()
        fl.loadData()
```

I am calling `PatDataLoader.load("test","test.txt")` from another module.  The problem I am running into is the application crashes with `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running` as there seems to be a problem with the thread process I am passing to the fileloader.  Am I not putting these pieces together properly?

main.py:

```
from lmdb.patloader import PatDataLoader


    class PPSReportsApp(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, *args):
            super(PPSReportsApp, self).__init__(*args)
            loadUi("GlobalUI/ppsreportswindow.ui", self)
            #self.showMaximized()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_actionTest_triggered(self):
        pl = PatDataLoader()
        pl.load("TEST","testfile.txt")
```

Comment: You could show how you call PatDataLoader, that is, the main.

Comment: I am calling it from a menu trigger in a QMainWindow class.  See edited code

Comment: typos: `self.thread **a** ctive = True` and `self.thread **A** ctive = False`

Comment: Ahh yes.  I corrected the typo; however, the problem still persists.  It never gets to the run method of the thread.

Comment: Yes, I know, but typos distract, you should avoid not to distract us with them.

Comment: Corrected in the post

Comment: try with my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `pl` is a local variable so it will be deleted when it finishes executing `on_actionTest_triggered` which is an instant possibly generating that problem. On the other hand, no load should be a static method because it does not use the self. self.thread must be `None`, it is better than `""`

**How can you prevent `pl` from being deleted before it is finished processing?**

`fl` is a `QDialog` so you can use `exec_()`.

**fileloader.py**

```
class FileLoader(QDialog):
    completeSig = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FileLoader, self).__init__(parent)
        self.filename = ""
        self.clientcode = ""
        self.thread = None
        loadUi("GlobalUI/fileloader.ui", self)
        self.prgLoader.setValue(0)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_btnCancel_clicked(self):
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        if self.thread:
            self.thread.stop()

    def loadData(self):
        if self.thread:
            self.thread.totalSig.connect(self.prgLoader.setMaximum)
            self.thread.countSig.connect(self.prgLoader.setValue)
            self.thread.finished.connect(self.completed)
            self.thread.start()

    def completed(self):
        self.completeSig.emit()
        self.close()
```

**loader.py**

```
class DataLoader(QThread):
    totalSig = pyqtSignal(int)
    countSig = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DataLoader, self).__init__(parent)
        self.threadactive = True
        self.commitsize = 300
        self.rowdata = []

    def run(self):
        self.totalSig.emit(1000)
        print("Code Will Go Here For Loading the File")
        # emulate process
        for i in range(1000):
            if self.threadactive:
                QThread.msleep(10)
                self.countSig.emit(i)

    def stop(self):
        self.threadactive = False
        self.quit()
        self.wait()

class PatDataLoader():
    @staticmethod
    def load(clientcode, filename):
        fl = FileLoader()
        fl.clientcode = clientcode
        fl.filename = filename
        fl.thread = DataLoader()
        fl.loadData()
        fl.exec_() # <---
```

**main.py**

```
@pyqtSlot()
def on_actionTest_triggered(self):
    PatDataLoader.load("TEST","testfile.txt")
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks for the advice and I will read up more on the exec_() method.